# Visual studio doesn't copy the .pdb file into Appx folder

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I was debugging a UWP app. I found that the exception stack trace doesn't contain the line numbers. After a lot of tests, I found that the .pdb file doesn't be copied to the Appx folder. Maybe, it's the root issue. How to deal with this issue?

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
Version 15.9.4

Comment: Hi Xie, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps,  please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just handle your issue that how to add pdb files into appx folder.

There are two ways:

**1)** MSBuild by default removes all the `pdb` files during the generation of the appx. You can add this xml node under app.csproj file to enable that.

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols>true</AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** You could embed the pdb file into the exe file so that the debugging info will act with the exe without worrying about losing a separate pdb file.

Right-click on the **Project Properties**-->**Build**-->**Advanced**-->change **Debug Information** to `Embedded`.